# WCF with Message Serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm write a simple wcf service that submit request to some gateway to be processed.

The request are being executed by executing something like that:

I'm writing a WCF service that submit a request to some service which expect to get something like this:

```
gatewayService.SendRequest(request);
```

where gatewayService is the WCF proxy and request is my own object which inherit form WCF Message object.

The request object has few properties like:

```
[MessageBodyMember]
public ReportCommandLineRequest ReportRequest { get; set; }

[MessageBodyMember]
public ImportCommandLineRequest ImportRequest { get; set; }
```

My problem is when this request object is being serialized. On the server side i'm getting a big chunky soap message that looks like that:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IReportClient/RunReport/IGatewayAdapter/SendRequest</a:Action>
      <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo4jiWNjcsdxHiUhlOA63xYEAAAAApgt+BuVvcEixP33+yOQTgRHZQSyr4L5ImMHVeEWLFBMACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">net.tems://localhost:7222/queue/LB.FIA.Gateway.STAGE.InputQueue</a:To>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <SendRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/IReportClient/RunReport">
          <request xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07....
```

On the other hand, i expect on the server side to get only the serialization of the properties listed above (ReportRequest/ImportRequest), and hoping to get a serialized xml looks like that (without all the garbage inside:

```
<ReportCommandLineRequest>
  <outputFileName>gatewayReportOutput-01082010-150043.pdf</outputFileName>
  <CommandLineArg
    name="format"
..
</ReportCommandLineRequest>
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out how can i do that?

Thank.

Comment: thank you; i didn't know about this and i will follow going forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF **IS** a SOAP based message service - so the fact you're getting a "big chunky soap message" is sort of "by design", really!

But what's the problem really?? SOAP is a well-defined protocol, and every decent web service platform speaks and understands SOAP.

Plus, typically, in WCF, you don't deal with "raw" messages anyway - you define your data structures that your service and client exchange, you define classes as `[DataContract]` that gets sent back and forth, and you let WCF and SOAP handle all the nitty-gritty details of serializing and deserializing your message from and to XML. Typically, you don't have to deal with any of that at all.

So once again: what is really the challenge or question here? WCF is SOAP (and now also REST) - so why does that SOAP message surprise you or cause problems??

WCF also supports handling "raw" messages, and it allows you to do things like extract the body from a SOAP message and so forth (or tweak it otherwise). See some of these blog posts for some pointers on what is possible and what you can do:

- [WCF : Untyped messages on WCF operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108121405/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/claeyskurt/archive/2008/09/24/125430.aspx)
- [WCF - Handling Generic Messages](https://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/wcf-handling-generic-messages)
- [Obtaining an Untyped WCF Message from a Typed Service Operation](https://web.archive.org/web/20111106124232/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/06/15/obtaining-an-untyped-wcf-message-from-a-typed-service-operation.aspx)
- [Accessing the message inside of your WCF service operations](https://web.archive.org/web/20081230005511/http://blogs.thinktecture.com:80/cweyer/archive/2008/06/05/415161.aspx)
- [WCF Intermediate Service between Client and Server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29775/WCF-Intermediate-Service-between-Client-and-Server)

Comment: hi marc, i agree with you, no argument about that. however, the server side only supports the "clean" format, i.e, only the xml part that i described above. is there anywhere to convert those messages to be the "full" body of the message?

Thanks